# Create a graph in Excel 2010 using 3 columns of data

Tags: excel, graph, datatable, excel-2010

I have been looking online tirelessly for a solution to the following problem but to no avail. I am trying to create a seasonal plot for the table below. My goal is to plot sales against quarter, classified by year.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these look like something you want to get?

[image]
[image]

I used fake data just over 3 years.

Each years is represented by a line.

Each line spans over 4 quarters.

To make this you select:

1) Series are years => 3 years = 3 series, Give each a name (e.g. 2003)
and input values so for year 2003 my values are `=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$4`

2) Then on the right edit your X-axis the values there are `=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$12`

3) Adjust labels and formatting

**EDIT**

[image]

For this you'll have to combine year and quarters as shown e.g. `2003 Q1`
I guess you can't create a 2-dimensional chart using all 3 inputs

Comment: Thanks Andy. While this would usually be a great way to plot seasonal data, what I am specifically trying to do is have only one line on the graph, but with both year and quarter on the x-axis, sales on the y-axis.

Comment: Don't know how else you may do it, check my edit - there I have `time` on X and `$` on Y-axis

Answer (score 1):

Make the following modifications to your data.

1. Clear the cells above the years and the quarters.
2. Remove all but the first instance of each year in the first column.

Select the data range and insert your chart. You will get a category axis with two levels, quarter close to the axis and year below that. This is the technique in my tutorial [Chart with a Dual Category Axis](http://peltiertech.com/categorical-archive-of-the-pts-blog/).

I've illustrated this with a subset of your data (note blank cells with faint yellow shading). You can make a column or line chart directly from this data.

[image: Chart with Years and Quarters on Category Axis]